# subnet mask ip address

Tags: ip, subnet

I have a device having IP address 192.168.1.** and subnet 255.255.255.0 I access that device on my pc through web servers by entering IP address of that device on the browser.

By mistake I changed its subnet mask to 255.255.255.255 now I am not able to access it. I can't change its subnet mask manually.

How do I access device having the IP address 192.168.1.** and subnet mask 255.255.255.255 through the computer?

Comment: What kind of device are you trying to access? Can you post screenshots of what you are seeing? It is fine to post local private IP addresses, we all have the same ones. Try connecting your computer directly to the device in question, or with a switch between, and set a static IP on your computer in the 192.168.1.x range, and try to access your device.

Comment: can i connect computer directly through that device lan port and access it by entering its ip address on a browser..just like isp modem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking you can't! Subnet 255.255.255.255 only allows for one IP, so you can not put a second device on this subnet. There are ways to solve it but they are complicated (at least the ideas that spring to my mind right away).

Therefore I would suggest resetting the device to its factory defaults. And then set up new IP settings (and the other settings as well). It will take you much less time this way.

Comment: can i connect computer  directly through that device lan port and access it by entering its ip address on a browser..just like isp modem

Comment: @laxmankokane is that a question or a statment?

Comment: can i connect computer directly through that device lan port and access it by entering its ip address on a browser..just like isp modem?

Comment: No, because the device is configured to be on a subnet of 1 IP.  There’s no IP you can assign to your computer so it’s on the same network as the device.

Comment: @laxmankokane GregW is correct

Comment: what is the solution ?

Comment: @laxmankokane as I stated in my answer: I would suggest resetting the device to factory settings.